# Slim framework and GET/PUT/POST methods

Tags: api, methods, httprequest, slim

For example, i use this code for testing routes:

```
$app->get('/api', function () {                         
        echo 'get!';
});
$app->post('/api', function () {                            
        echo 'post!';
});
$app->put('/api', function () {                         
        echo 'put!';
});
```

For api testing i use RestClient plugin for Chrome.

When i try do GET request, response is 'get!'. Its good.

But:

1. When i try do POST request, response also is  'get!'. Why? Its must be 'post!'.
2. When i try do PUT request, (in Response Headers: Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS,TRACE ) Slim response have 405 error (Method Not Allowed) with message:

> "The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /api."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works for me using [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) and [DHC - REST/HTTP API Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm). Did you add ``.htaccess`` file?

Comment: yes, this my htaccess: 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php

Comment: Try to use [this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeguy/Slim/master/.htaccess).

Comment: It's nice to see that it works. For order purpose, I've created an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure that your `.htaccess` is the following (from [slimphp/Slim@2.x](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slimphp/Slim/2.x/.htaccess)):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. The link by Davide Pastore doesn't work for me and this is what finally helped me get everything working after two days of pulling out my hair. Much appreciated.

Comment: @ramijames thanks for your comment. I've updated my answer fixing the broken link and the `.htaccess` content.