# Error 404 with web service on slim framework

Tags: php, web-services, slim

If I use this reour `http://localhost/esi3d/` with this method it works correctly

```
$app->get(
"/", function () use($app){
    $db = new Db_handler;
    $result = $db->select_all("clase");

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $dependency[] = $row ;
    }
    $struct = array("Dependencies"=>$dependency);

    $app->response->headers->set("Content-type","application/json");
    $app->response->status(200);
    $app->response->body(json_encode($struct));
}
);
```

but if I try to use a parameter I get a 404 error using that route `http://localhost/esi3d/clase` to use this method

```
$app->get(
"/:table", function ($table) use($app){
    $db = new Db_handler;
    $result = $db->select_all($table);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $dependency[] = $row ;
    }
    $struct = array("Dependencies"=>$dependency);

    $app->response->headers->set("Content-type","application/json");
    $app->response->status(200);
    $app->response->body(json_encode($struct));
}
);
```

Comment: What is your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Be sure to have one with [this content](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28409423/1992780).