# PHP Slim Framework: The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, .htaccess, api, rest, slim

For one of the projects, i am using Slim Framework http://www.slimframework.com/ to create restful APIs in PHP.

I did a manual install for the framework by copying it in the PHP project folder using instructions at https://github.com/slimphp/Slim.

Later i updated my .htaccess as well.

For my project, I have the following Directory Structure

```
project\
----slim\
----tests\
----index.php
----.htaccess
```

For this, the Get call i.e. http://someIp/project/ works for me. It fetches the standard "Welcome to Slim! Congratulations! Your Slim application is running. If this is your first time using Slim, start with this "Hello World" Tutorial."
However, post/patch/delete and other get are not working. Not even get for hello. It gives the not found error.

http://someIp/project/hello/:name
The requested URL /project/hello/:name was not found on this server.

http://someIp/project/post
The requested URL /project/post was not found on this server.

Updated my .htaccess file as :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Still it is failing.

When i made changes into the apache config file to allowOverride = all, it failed even for the GET call on index.php. For sure, it is not mapping from .htaccess.

I am still clueless what changes i need to make to .htaccess or any other file to get it working.

Here is the code:

```
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

/**
 * Step 2: Instantiate a Slim application
 *
 * This example instantiates a Slim application using
 * its default settings. However, you will usually configure
 * your Slim application now by passing an associative array
 * of setting names and values into the application constructor.
 */
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

/**
 * Step 3: Define the Slim application routes
 *
 * Here we define several Slim application routes that respond
 * to appropriate HTTP request methods. In this example, the second
 * argument for `Slim::get`, `Slim::post`, `Slim::put`, `Slim::patch`, and `Slim::delete`
 * is an anonymous function.
 */

// GET route
$app->get(
    '/',
    function () {
        $template = "hi";
        echo $template;
    }
);

//$app->get(
//    '/v1/status/',
//    function() {
//        echo "status";
//    }
//);
//
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});

// POST route
$app->post(
    '/post',
    function () {
        echo 'This is a POST route';
    }
);

// PUT route
$app->put(
    '/put',
    function () {
        echo 'This is a PUT route';
    }
);

// PATCH route
$app->patch('/patch', function () {
    echo 'This is a PATCH route';
});

// DELETE route
$app->delete(
    '/delete',
    function () {
        echo 'This is a DELETE route';
    }
);

/**
 * Step 4: Run the Slim application
 *
 * This method should be called last. This executes the Slim application
 * and returns the HTTP response to the HTTP client.
 */
$app->run();
```

Comment: Have you actually defined the routes in index.php?

Comment: i have the default routes in index.php, and they dont seem to be workin

Comment: Did you add $app->run() to the end of the index.php? This is a mistake I frequently make :)

Comment: @Tuim it is already there.. i am using the existing code they have for Hello

Comment: The hello world example in the readme only defines one GET route. It does not define any POST or PUT routes. Please include the code you are using in your question se we can understand what code you are using.

Comment: @MikaTuupola updated the code.. not sure why someone downvoted this question... :/

Comment: Can you try with [this .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28409423/1992780)?

Comment: @DavidePastore where do i keep this htaccess inside root or inside subdirectory

Comment: Inside your root directory.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following steps worked for me :

### Changes in apache2.conf

```
1. Get the path of running Apache
    ps -ef | grep apache
   Append -V argument to the path
    /usr/sbin/apache2 -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE

2. Naviagte to apache2.conf
    vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

3. Update the file Replace "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All"
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
4. Restart apache2 after
    service apache2 restart
   OR
    apachectl -k graceful
```

### Changes in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

### Changes in .htaccess inside subdirectory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

### Enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2

```
1. Type the following command in the terminal
    a2enmod rewrite
2. Restart apache2 after
    service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Perfect answer... Wasted my 6 precious hours.. thanks

Comment: it helps too lot. perfect answer !!

Comment: Changes in apache conf was the way to go for me, default domain was working fine but one in new Virtual Host was not. this solve it.