# Slim Framework does not work on Mac (windows ok)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

I am developing an API on a Windows machine that works fine on that machine. When I pull the source code from git to my Mac machine, the GET or POST requests that has parameters not working.

To be more specific:

```
GET /token/ 200 OK
GET /token/1 error 404
```

The call of the get method into the index.php that is in `/token/` path is:

```
$app->get('/', function() { ...
$app->get('/:id_token', function($id_token) use($app) { ...
```

Still, into `/token/` path I have the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The `mod_rewrite.so` is on and the Directory into httpd.conf is like that:

```
<Directory "/Users/Lourenci/Sites/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In Windows it works, not to Mac.

What is wrong? I do not know what else to setup! I will go crazy with that!

Sorry for my english, I am a Brazilian user.

Tks.

Comment: Is your mod-rewrite module active on the Mac ?

Comment: Hmm, what happens if you type gibberish (`lshdf`) into the `.htaccess` file? Do you get a `500 Internal Server Error`?

Comment: Yes, I get a 500 internal server error.

Comment: @Lourenci Did you try using the recommended `.htaccess` (that you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28409423/1992780))?