# 404 Error when using SLIM framework routing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

I have my SLIM PHP app in `http://www.example.com/API/`

I have routing in my `index.php` like so:

```
$app->get('/getstudents', function() use($app) {
    $db = new DbHandler();
    $result = $db->getAllStudents();

    if ($result === false) {
        echo "Failed to fetch";
    } else {
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
});

$app->run();
```

When I try the url with `curl http://example.com/API/getstudents` I get the error **The requested URL /API/getstudents was not found on this server.**

If I use `curl http://example.com/API/index.php/getstudents` the list of students is returned as expected. I've googled around and understand that this may be because of the `.htaccess` file and/or the virtual host setup.

So I have made a copy of `.htaccess` from `API/vendor/slim/slim/.htaccess` to the API folder so it is in the same folder as `index.php`. In this file I have:

```
# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /API/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

No luck with this. Do I need to change the contents of the `.htaccess` file in both the API directory and API/vendor/slim/slim/?

I'm also not entirely sure what I need to do to my virtual host file. In /etc/apache2/sites-available I am editing *example.com.conf*, contents are:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.co
  ServerName  www.example.co
  ServerAlias example.co
  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.co/public_html
  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/html/example.co/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/example.co/logs/access.log combined
  <Directory "/var/www/html/example.co/public_html">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Could someone please give me some pointers to what I might be doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try using [this .htaccess file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28409423/1992780)?

Answer (score 1):

## First thing to do:

#### Change your route to this:

```
$app->get('/API/getstudents', function() use($app) {
```

## If that does not work do the following:

Solve this problem making your routes like this:

```
$app->get('/api/book', function () {
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $data = Book::getBookObjects();
    echo $data;
});
```

> This is an example of one project of mine, you can user API instead of api.

The .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The working tree of my project is like this:

`Project Folder -> public -> .htaccess, index.php`

`Project Folder -> api -> book`

#### Adapting your code:

```
$app->get('/api/getstudents', function() use($app) {
    $db = new DbHandler();
    $result = $db->getAllStudents();
    if ($result === false) {
        echo "Failed to fetch";
    } else {
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
});

$app->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create `.htaccess` file in API place where is your index.php file with data

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: sorry it's a different error now : <p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>

Comment: for some reason what is in the .htaccess file is now causing an error

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this answer](https://discourse.slimframework.com/t/slim-4-httpnotfoundexception/3273/20) on the Slim forum :

If your Slim app is not on the server root path (`http://<host>/[index.php]`), you'll have to state the full path to your route.

Let's take this url for example : `http://<host>/staging/`.

You have then two options to achieve our goal :

- States the path in all your routes `$app->get('/staging/', handler);` and so on, or
- States it a single time after the app creation `$app->SetBasePath('/staging');`